# Upload_Path_Handler file path for Django ImageField cannot retrieve image in HTML file

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I've attempted to use **Upload_Path_Handler** in order to allow for dynamic folder names *(such as the upload date, item ID, etc.)* in saving image files uploaded by users, so as to prevent duplicate instances.

The problem is that the directory which I've returned is too 'deep' to be retrieved through the HTML file, in that, it begins with the name of the app (in this case, 'vault'). The broken path served for the image in the HTML file is as follows:

```
<img src="vault/static/vault/images/recordimages/r_1/2017-12-09_03-27-42/300x300.jpg">
```

However, by using inspector element to exclude the app name 'vault' at the beginning, I am able to successfully retrieve the image:

```
<img src="/static/vault/images/recordimages/r_1/2017-12-09_03-27-42/300x300.jpg">
```

---

The broken path is served in the raw html file as:

```
<img src="{{ record.w_image }}">
```

And the model referenced, w_image, is as follows in models.py:

```
w_image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Record Image:', upload_to=upload_path_handler)
```

Then, of course, is upload_path_handler:

```
def upload_path_handler(self, filename):
    return "vault/static/vault/images/recordimages/r_{id}/{date}/{file}".format(id=self.id, file=filename, date=datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
```

If I were to begin the return path at /static/, it would then instead save the images in WebsiteName/static/../.. as opposed to WebsiteName/vault/static/../.. *(Remember, the aim here is to keep the /static/ directory a subdirectory of our app, 'vault')*

How can I allow for the image to be retrievable without compromising on the path as a subdirectory of 'vault'?

Comment: Apart from anything else, you should certainly use a leading underscore: `/vault/...` not `vault/...`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write image url, like this:

```
<img src="{{ record.w_image.url }}">
```

Comment: Hi there. I have attempted your suggestion, but unfortunately, this does not seem to correct the issue. The image URL remains unchanged.

Comment: Did you configure MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py and main urls.py?

Comment: I've found it in the docs. Would it suffice to say that I should refrain from providing my own media directories as the subdirectories of my apps, and instead pack them all into one root /media/ directory? I'm assuming that I can only specify one directory as MEDIA_ROOT in the settings.py.

Comment: Without configuring media root and url django doesn't know where is this image. read more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/